# Transparency not working as desired with Haskell OpenGL

Tags: haskell, opengl

I've done this polyhedron with Haskell OpenGL:

[image]

The sides of the polyhedron are transparent:

```
renderPrimitive Quads $ do
  materialDiffuse Front $= col
  ......
```

where `col` is a color with "a" component equal to `0.2`.

And in the `main` function, the blending is enabled:

```
blend $= Enabled
blendFunc $= (SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha)
```

One can see that the sides are indeed transparent. However the edges of the polyhedron do not appear in the interior. Why that? I have tried numerous `initialDisplayMode`, such as:

```
initialDisplayMode $= [RGBAMode, DoubleBuffered, WithDepthBuffer, WithAlphaComponent]
```

I have these material colors and light colors:

```
clearColor $= Color4 0 0 0 0
materialSpecular Front $= white
materialShininess Front $= 50
lighting $= Enabled
light (Light 0) $= Enabled
position (Light 0) $= Vertex4 0 0 100 1
ambient (Light 0) $= white
diffuse (Light 0) $= white
specular (Light 0) $= white
```

Comment: I think you need to disable the depth buffer, and draw the polygons back to front.  Blending is a pain.

Comment: Do you use face culling?

Comment: @luqui Sorry, what do you mean by "drawing back to front" ?

Comment: @Ripi2 I have tried the face culling, reversing the order of the vertices, negating the normals... no way :-(

Comment: If culling is disabled then it seems a depth issue, like @luqui said. "back to front" means "far objects are drawn first"

Comment: Ah yes, this works if I draw the edges before drawing the facets! I didn't know the order has an importance :-/

Comment: With depth testing enabled the new nearer fragment replaces the old further one.

Comment: Why the downvotes ? The question is not clear ? Or not legit ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent my guess is you have not provided enough information.  E.g. the code to draw the polygons, what windowing library, etc.  But haskell tag is getting some random question hate lately though, too, I don't get it.

Comment: @luqui Hmm ok. But they could ask for more information instead of downvoting, the question is editable :-/ Thanks for your help !

Comment: Don't worry too much for the downvotes, as long as you also have upvotes: an upvote is +10 rep and a downvote is only -2 rep. Anyway: the drawing order usually does not matter, since the z-buffer (depth buffer) handles that in hardware for us. Essentially, the color of each pixel becomes the color of the point closer to the camera, no matter what order we choose. When mixing colors of multiple surfaces ("blending"), it's more complicated, and the z-buffer (AFAICS) does not help so much, and order matters again.

Comment: Order of drawing is only important if you are enabling depth test as blending will be applied to fragments those pass depth test. So if you draw fragment which is in front then draw fragment in behind it will lose depth test and will give wrong blending results . So if enabling depth test draw surfaces from behind to front so all surfaces pass z test and will go to blending. Else just disable blending and then use appropriate blend func and draw.